# How to disable the facet in solr externally through a query if it is true in the qt defination

Tags: apache, solr

I want to disable the facet thrpough the query.
i am having a qt as tester with facet=true and facet.field = city
i am using a query like
localhost:8983/solr/mywork/select?q=*:*&qt=tester
i want to false the facet field through the query and not changing the qt.How can i do this.

Answer (score 0):

`qt` used to choose a request handler. when 'qt' is not specified, the default handler is chosen which is usually `/select`.

All handler are defined in solrconfig.xml file. open that file and search  for request handler with name `tester` see how it defined for faceting, there you can modify facet defaults.

if you see line like this
`<str name="facet">on</str>` delete things related to facet.

Restart solr and try again.

Comment: change it to off/false `<str name="facet">false</str>` to disable facet functionality

Comment: I dont want to do changes in the qt how can i off the city facet through the command line as in some conditions i want city facet to be applied and in some cases not.So how can i do this ? Is there any other way i can do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can control faceting from query by giving **facet** param as ***true*** or ***false***.

- *facet = true*

> `localhost:8983/solr/mywork/select?q=:&qt=tester&facet=true&facet.field=city`

- *facet = false*

> `localhost:8983/solr/mywork/select?q=:&qt=tester&facet=false`

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your reply. But i have 3 facet in my qt as city,price and 1 more.I want only the city filter to be false for some specific queries. How can i do that because like this all the facet fill get off

Comment: facet fields results are list, you can choose to use only the other two and not the city, or at query time don't give facet.field=city for specific queries.

Answer (score 0):

The correct settings are  'on' or 'off'  (not true or false).

If you want to disable all faceting for a specific RequestHandler, this is how I've implemented it:

```
  <requestHandler name="/Spellcheck" class="org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler">
<lst name="defaults">
  <str name="df">NOSEARCH</str>
  <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">default</str>
  <str name="spellcheck">on</str>
</lst>
<lst name="invariants">
    <str name="rows">0</str>
    <str name="facet">off</str>
</lst>
<arr name="last-components">
  <str>spellcheck</str>
</arr>
```

The section that is relevant to preventing the user of facets with the handler is the 'invariants' section. This over-rides any of the settings passed in the command.